# AWS OpenSearch Instance Types - better to have few bigger or more smaller instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch, instancetype

I am a junior dev ops engineer and have this very basic question.

My team is currently working on providing an AWS OpenSearch cluster. Due to the type of our problem, we require the storage-optimized instances. From the amazon documentation I found that they recommend a minimum number of 3 nodes. The required storage size is known to me, in the OpenSearch Service pricing calculator I found that I can either choose 10 i3.large instances or 5 i3.xlarge ones. I checked the prices, they are the same.

So my question is, when I am faced with such a problem, do I choose the lesser bigger instances or the bigger number of smaller instances? I am particularly interested in the reason.

Thank you!

Comment: You haven't mentioned if this cluster will contain master nodes. If no, you SHOULD otherwise you will have big issues if the load increase. As for the worker nodes, I guess it depends more on sharding at this point as RAM, CPU and space is similar with 5 big and 10 small. How many primary and secondary shards you would like equally distributed among all the nodes.

Comment: @Riz Thank you! We have one primary shard and one replica shard. We have 5 shards (so that the target size is between 10 and 50GB). We also have 3 master nodes which are in good health.

Comment: As @ilvar has said in the answer, it's better to have 5 bigger ones than 10. Supposing you have multiaz for this domain, your total shards will be 10(2 each node, 1 primary+1 replica). Also, keep your shards under 800 per node. How many indices will there be? and what is the retention period for each index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each VM has some overhead for the OS so 10 smaller instances would have *less* compute and RAM available for ES in total than 5 larger instances. Also, if you just leave the default index settings (5 primary shards, 1 replica) and actively write to only 1 index at a time, you'll effectively have only 5 nodes indexing data for you (and these nodes will have less bandwidth because they are smaller).

So, I would usually recommend running a few larger instances instead of many smaller ones. There are some special cases where it won't be true (like a concurrent-search-heavy cluster) but for those, I'd recommend going with even larger instances in the first place.